# Saving and retrieving data in google drive from android app

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I want to make an android app where user will record a daily life events in the form of text, audio and video. I want to save the data to google drive of a particular user and retrieve the data when needed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is [Google Drive Apis](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk)